# Application of invariant method

Tags: elementary-number-theory, invariance

On the board is written the number $18$. Every minute the number is replaced by the product with 2 or 3,or by the quotient of the division with 2 or 3. Show that after $60$ minutes the number cannot be $96$.

What I tried is to factorize into prime: $18=2\cdot3^2$ and $96=2^5\cdot3$, but I don't see what the invariant is, since the division by $2$ or $3$ may result in new prime factors.

Comment: If I interpret the instructions right, you can only divide by $p$ if the number written is a multiple of $p$. So if you start with a division by $2$ and get $9$, the next step can't be another division by $2$.

Comment: @Daniel Fisher  you can divide by p even if it is not a multiple of p. you just discard the reminder. if you have 27 and divide by 2 then you obtain 13

Comment: Well, that's not how I interpret "divide without remainder".

Comment: I see how that can be. I edited my post

Comment: In particular, since with allowing $\lfloor n/p\rfloor$, it is possible to have 96 after 60 minutes.

Comment: If you can divide by $2$ when $n$ is odd the problem becomes false, you can get to $1$ in $4$ steps: $18\mapsto 9 \mapsto 4\mapsto 2 \mapsto 1$ and then you have an even number of moves left, this lets you get to $96$ and then swap between $96$ and $192$, after $60$ minutes you're at $96$ because $\Omega(1)$ has the same parity as $\Omega(96)$.

Comment: yes the problem seems to be misleading I think you can only divide by $\mathit{p}$ if the number written is a multiple of **p** as Daniel Fischer said

Comment: There is no problem even if we allow for example division by $2$ twice from $18$. The result is $2^{-1}\cdot 3^2$, and the parity argument still works. It also works if we do not allow division that results in a non-integer answer. It does not work if for example we think that the result of dividing $3$ by $2$ is $1$. Under those conditions, we can get to $96$ in $60$ steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: At any time, the number has the shape $2^a\cdot 3^b$. A useful invariant is the **parity** of $a+b$, that is, the remainder when $a+b$ is divided by $2$.

The parity changes every minute, so it must be unchanged after an even number of minutes.

Comment: that seems to be the answer , thank you

Comment: You are welcome. It is an invariant argument, but a special case sometimes called a parity argument, or a colouring argument.

Answer (score 0):

Denote by $\Omega(n)$ the number of prime factors of $n$ counting multiplicity, so if $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\dots p_r^{\alpha_r}$ then $\Omega(n)=\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\dots + \alpha_r$.

Initially the number on the board $N$ is $18=2\cdot3^2$ so $\Omega(N)$ is odd. After every step we add $1$ or substract $1$ from one of the prime exponents, and thus $\Omega(N)$ changes parity at each operation.

After $60$ minutes the parity of $\Omega(N)$ has changed $60$ times, so it has stayed the same, in other words it is odd.

On the other hand $\Omega(96)=\Omega(2^53^1)=6$ which is even.

---

Incidentally $\Omega(N)$ is a very studied function in analytic number theory, it even has an [OEIS page](http://oeis.org/wiki/Omega%28n%29,_number_of_prime_factors_of_n_%28with_multiplicity%29)